# How to Grab information from an XMLHttp request and convert into an array.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on an app and have gotten stuck. I have created a XMLHttp request and need to pull the information from it and put it into an array so I can create markers out of the request on a google map. The code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper
} from 'google-maps-react';


//"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7589,-73.9851&query=food&radius=2000&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&client_id=INOHETWKCQHOZUPUATJJ503RCWMUXPFUOCJCHRN2LRADAZJO&client_secret=1ABUWB4S3QS41A50X1UJFHC4THA2YQGOBNOBUSRARLZ4DE5W&v=20201215&limit=25"
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search? ll=40.7589,-73.9851&query=food&radius=2000&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&client_id=INOHETWKCQHOZUPUATJJ503RCWMUXPFUOCJCHRN2LRADAZJO&client_secret=1ABUWB4S3QS41A50X1UJFHC4THA2YQGOBNOBUSRARLZ4DE5W&v=20201215&limit=25"
Http.open('GET', url)
Http.send();

Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
  console.log(Http.responseText)
}



var  AllPlaces = [



]

class MapContainer extends Component {
state = {
showingInfoWindow: false,
activeMarker: {},
selectedPlace: {},
query:'',
filteredPlaces: []
};

markers = []


onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
this.setState({
selectedPlace: props,
activeMarker: marker,
showingInfoWindow: true
});
}

onLiClick = (i) =>{
this.setState({
showingInfoWindow: true,
activeMarker: this.markers[i],
selectedPlace: AllPlaces[i]
})
}


onMapClicked = (props) => {
if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
this.setState({
showingInfoWindow: false,
activeMarker: null
})
}
}


CreateInputField = () => (
<input
placeholder = "Search Nearby Places"
onChange={(event) => this.setState({filteredPlaces: AllPlaces.filter(place 
=> !place.name.startsWith((event.target.value).toLowerCase()))})}
/>
)

render() {
return (
<div className = 'map-container' role='application' style=
{{marginleft:'250px'}}>
<div>
  <div className = 'navMenu'>
    <div className = 'List'>
      <h1 className = 'title'> Places to Eat
</h1>
        {this.CreateInputField()}
    </div>
    <div className = 'PlaceList'>
      <ol className='Places'>
        {AllPlaces.map((arrayItem, index)=>
        !this.state.filteredPlaces.includes(arrayItem) &&
          <li
          key = {index}
          className='Place'
          onClick={() => {this.onLiClick(index)}}
          >{arrayItem.name}</li>
        )}
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}
  initialCenter = {{lat:40.7589, lng:-73.9851}}
  onClick={this.onMapClicked}>
  {AllPlaces.map((marker, i) =>
    !this.state.filteredPlaces.includes(marker) &&
      <Marker
      ref={(e) => {if (e) this.markers[i] =
  e.marker}}
      onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
      title = {marker.name}
      key = {i}
      name={marker.name}
      position =
{{lat:marker.lat,lng:marker.lng}}
      />
  )}
  <InfoWindow
    onOpen={this.windowHasOpened}
    onClose={this.windowHasClosed}
    marker={this.state.activeMarker}
    visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
    <div>
      <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
    </div>
  </InfoWindow>
</Map>
</div>
);
}
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
apiKey: 'AIzaSyD2BmXOGrCZQiAg5HJ6hU70BXc5v6Osr6M'
})(MapContainer)
```

I need to take in information I get from the XML request and put each object into the array I have at the top called AllPlaces I have tried with response and response text but have no idea how to loop through the JSON object that is returned.

Comment: Make sure you remove your API Key before sharing with other people :)

Comment: You could do a foreach loop through the response object. And then manually push each item into your array.

Comment: @AnthonySobo how would that look, I am trying to loop through with for each but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: When you say doesn't work what exactly do you mean? Are you getting an error when you try to loop?

Comment: @AnthonySobo No, nothing gets logged to the console when I try to loop over it